# How to apply CSS3 rendering for optimal performance

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm creating a web application and after reaching a certain degree of complexity, I notice that whenever I'm using the page, my laptop's fan starts to run high, perhaps from processor or video card. I've only seen it behave like this in games or graphical processing before.

I profiled the javascript and noticed no processes consuming too much resources, so I thought perhaps it could be the CSS.

I am using some animations with **transition**, **translate** and **opacity**.

My question is: Will these CSS properties affect my performance? How to use these elements in an optimal way? Might be a broad (not too broad) question, but any tips would greatly help.

Comment: Yes, they will. Browsers will offload rendering to the GPU when it sees the need so: and whether there is such a need depends from browser to browser. In general, forcing a 3D transform (e.g. translating, rotating along the z-axis) will cause the browser to ring up the GPU for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Terry mentions, using the transform matrix will make the browser pass that to the GPU, but you also need to be careful about it.

Normally desktops and laptops handle this very good (unless you're passing big images, huge SVG's or a lot of them at the same time, in that scenario there's not much any normal GPU in a computer/device can do), but devices still do have less powerful hardware so don't use too much. Finally using translate properties instead of left and top for example, do increase browser performance since rendering is done in the GPU.

If you're interested in JS animation, a solid choice would be using [Greensock](http://greensock.com) since it has the ability to create a GPU layer and then remove it, in order to avoid clogging the GPU. Also handles garbage collection in an excellent way. I've used in many projects with excellent results, also you don't need a lot of JS knowledge to use it.

Edit:

@raphadko, I believe is good to look at this video to understand the most basic issues regarding browser rendering performance:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xx_dkv9DEY

Comment: Just a small note, few browsers uses GPU when handling SVG. I've heard that IE and Edge are the only ones doing a good work there.

Comment: Is using transition: all somehow worse than using just transition:width? Sometimes I just need width to be animated for example, but using all makes the css easier.

Comment: I'm not a CSS animations/transitions expert(as mentioned I use Greensock), but to my understanding it shouldn't be much of a difference. The real gotcha in animation is the browser calculating, applying and rendering the styles changes. What you could do in order to improve is use a low translateZ like 0.1px in order to force that element into a GPU layer for better rendering. Although if you want to use another transform property, you'll have to use the full 3D matrix, which includes all 16 values (that's why I use Greensock), but if you only need one property then there's no problem.